# how to limit maxlogin for a port forward over ssh user who Do not execute a remote command

Tags: shell, login, port-forwarding, pam

I have some users, who connect to my server through the ssh for port forwarding and ssh tunneling, but there is a problem:
I cannot limit their concurrent logins, because they have no session and cannot access to any shell.
In this case, PAM and Limits file, wont help.

Answer (score 0):

According to [OpenSSH FAQ](http://www.openssh.org/faq.html#3.15) you could use PAM for ssh authentication.

Comment: "Use Pam" option on ssh configuration file is enabled, But It won't help cause in port forwarding mode, i disabled their access to Shell, and Pam's do nothing.

Comment: Do you have anything in pam configuration for ssh (/etc/pam.d/sshd)?